# Excel VBA - Label is blank first time running the form, later always 1 step behind

Tags: excel, vba, label, userform

I have a userform with 1 label (lword). The label needs to be updated with a variable every time the code is being run. Every time the code is being run the activecell changes and therefore also the value.

The first time the code is being run the label is blank (I deleted the default caption in the properties). The variable which should give the value to the label is being updated and shows the correct value. I included a MsgBox to test this (MsgBox word).

When you run the form for the second time or every time thereafter it shows always the previous value. Meaning updating the label seems always one step behind.

This is the code what I have so far:

```
Sub Random_Words()

Dim i As Integer
Dim word As String
Dim answer As String
Dim Rng As Range

i = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set Rng = Range("B1:B" & i)

Cells(Int((i * Rnd) + 1), 2).Select
word = ActiveCell.Value
answer = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value

MsgBox word

Load UserForm1
UserForm1.Show
UserForm1.lword.Caption = word

End Sub
```

I've been trying and reading several sites, but nothing worked out.
Also Userform1.Repaint doesn't help.

Thanks a lot in advance and in case you need more info, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the `ShowModal` property to `False` you will see the expected behavior.

When the line `UserForm1.Show` executes, while the form **is Modal**, the next line will not execute until you close the form yourself (actually it hides the form and allows the sub to continue). You never execute **`Unload`** in your code so the form remains and the the label's value is set to the new value of `word` after it is "closed". The next time you show the form (not re-load, actually), the old value is showing up, etc. To verify what I just described, modify your code like this:

```
    . . .
    MsgBox "word = " & word ' the new value is assigned to "word"

    Load UserForm1
    UserForm1.Show ' the old value of "word" is showing
    UserForm1.lword.Caption = word ' the new value is assigned to the label

    MsgBox "caption = " & UserForm1.lword.Caption

End Sub
```

Comment: You gotta be kidding me. I knew it was something simple, but not what...
It works indeed. Thanks a lot Gene.